# Angularjs keep the focus on a field after ng-click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mobile

I try to figure out how I can keep the focus on an input field in angularjs after I click on a button.

My goal is to prevent my mobile to hide his keyboard right after I click on the `+` button. I want to keep the focus on input `choice`.
Like this the user can add a new choice without the need to click again on my input.

```html
<div id="demo" ng-app="Foobar">
    <div ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="title" placeholder="title" />
        <input type="text" ng-model="choice" placeholder="choice" />
        <button ng-click="addChoice(choice)">+</button>
        {{choices}}
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
 angular.module('Foobar', [])
.controller('DemoCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.choices = [];

    $scope.addChoice = function (choice) {
        $scope.choices.push(choice);
    };
}]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gbg09bto/

What is the best strategy ? (directive, ng-focus)

Comment: The ng-focus directive would not help you, since ng-focus directive specifies custom behavior on focus event. What you want is something like $(element).focus() which I guess should be implemented in a directive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simplest thing is do it by plain javascript

to do it

in html // put a `id` attribute

```
<input type="text" id="choice" ng-model="choice" placeholder="choice" />
```

in controller function

```
$scope.addChoice = function (choice) {
    $scope.choices.push(choice);
    document.getElementById("choice").focus(); // get the element by id & focus the input
};
```

here is the updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ucq5esuo/)

Comment: Tested it on Chrome/Android and it indeed seems to work even when I repeatedly hammer the button. I was curious to see if the keyboard wouldn't disappear/reappear because of the very temporary loss of focus.